# Python strip newlines when saving a Django Model does not work

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When I make a request to my Django API I would like to to strip out newlines upon saving the model:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.title.replace("\r\n", "")
```

However this does not appear to work in the Django Admin it prints:

`Oranges\r\n`

```
curl -v -include --form name="test\r\n" --form raw_image=@test.jpg http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/fruit/
```

Comment: Strings are immutable, you need to re-assign the value returned by `.replace()` back to `self.title`.

Comment: i.e. ``self.title = self.title.replace("\r\n", "")`` ?

Comment: yep . `replace` is a function, it returns the new value, and doesn't touch the original value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.title.replace("\r\n", "")
```

Python removes any carriage return+linefeed pairs and then throws the result away.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.title = self.title.replace("\r\n", "")
```

will work, or you might even just do:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.title = self.title.rstrip()
```

if you only wanted to remove trailing newlines.